# How to add an variable value in between the hyperlink in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am sending an email via javascript. In `mail.parameter.text property` I need to send the hyperlink. In the code below I am hardcoding the url whick looks very lengthy and also I need to add the `/dashboard` at the end of the url. Any idea on how to shorten the url?

```
var parent = space.getParent();
var siteGroup = "GROUP_EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS";
var mail = actions.create("mail");
mail.parameters.to_many = siteGroup;
mail.parameters.subject="New Site Created in Community"
mail.parameters.text=" A new site called " + document.properties.name +"is created.Click http://pc1:8080/share/page/site/"+document.properties.name+"/dashboard"+"   to join the site";

//execute action against a document
mail.execute(document);
```

Sorry if this is a basic question I dont know javascript. This is my entire script and I am not using any html tags in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to something like this, for example:

```
mail.parameters.text="Click <a href='http://pc1:8080/share/page/site/" + document.properties.name + "/dashboard'>here</a>";
```

Your link will appear as "here" and nevertheless lead to the URL you specified. Is that what you mean by "shorten the url"?

Comment: how to add the end part `to join the site`. When I added I am getting missing semicolon error

Comment: I think you are confused by the single and double quotes. You need both types in order to separate the inner quoting from the outer, so to say.

Comment: `Click <a href='http://pc1:8080/share/page/site/sample/dashboard'>here</a>to join the site` This is what I got in email body

Comment: This looks absolutely valid to me inside a HTML mail... Are you sure that you are sending an HTML formatted mail? If you send a plain text mail, the a tag will not render and you will see the link as HTML source as seen above. In that case you need to make sure that you send a HTML mail.

Comment: So I need to add a external html email template and use that as an `mail.parameters.text`??

Comment: What you need to do depends on the framework you use, which I don't know anything about. Your mail gets created from an "actions"-object, which could be anything - it is not standard Javascript. You should refer to the manual of your framework or library.

Comment: Actually it is a javascript file written in alfresco share which will execute this file when a rule is satisfied. I will now look on to the library, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try now.

```
var url = "Click http://pc1:8080/share/page/site/" + document.properties.name + "/dashboard" + "   to join the site";
ail.parameters.text = url;
```

Comment: I just came to know that you need to reduce your code. if its not so then In which sense you want to shorten the url? in code ?

Comment: No the email body should be like this. `Click here to join the site.` The `here` should be a hyperlink to my website

Comment: Sorry I think you dont understand, it will still print the entire url in the email body. You can refer the answer by Robert. Thanks